# What is a word for a "soft" confused voice by a crowd?

Tags: single-word-requests

Tumult means a "**loud**" confused voice by a crowd. What is a word for a "**soft** (as the antonym to loud)" confused voice by a crowd? Imagine that you have made a statement to a crowd, and rather than a tumult, you hear confused whispers from the crowd that is clearly due to their confusion/disagreement/shock?

E.g. "I can hear you *tumult* as I give the news that war is coming close."
"I could see your tumult as you gave your back to your enemy and fled."

Whisper is not useful, because it does not imply confusion or disarray.

Comment: *Burbling, murmuring, humming, rambling*?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul thanks a good thread. Murmur seems appealing, but I'm not sure whether it implies confusion.

Comment: The question I linked has **15** answers, did you read all of them? It is a duplicate.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Thank you for that link. It seems that confused murmur would be a suitable word.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a term proper enough is "**hum**". *[hum](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hum_2)* a low continuous sound

Comment: hum is "a low continuous sound", it does not imply people whispering with each other with confusion or disagreement. hum is more like a *hmmmm* sound. Imagine someone makes a mistake on a scene, and can hear whispers in the crowd.

Comment: @hossein Here is an example which shows something like that (reaction from a crowd): https://books.google.fr/books?id=FDBiAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA150&dq=%22hum+from+the+crowd%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX-M-M0pLrAhUi5OAKHbHUAzEQ6AEwAXoECBcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22hum%20from%20the%20crowd%22&f=false (*There was a hum from the crowd at that because a good male slave would cost around twelve aurar of silver…*)

Comment: thank you. Didn't know it could be used like that!